# Replace String between 2 strings in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find all occurrences of a set of strings and replace what is in between them within a new value. I have tried all of the examples for Java/ regex I have found on this site and none have worked. A sample of the string would look like this:

```
"TestValue 1 VARCHAR(10), TestValue2 FLOAT(126), TestValue3 FLOAT(135)"
```

I would want to find and replace all the values between "FLOAT(" and ")" with 53 so that the above string would be replaced with:

```
"TestValue 1 VARCHAR(10), TestValue2 FLOAT(53), TestValue3 FLOAT(53)"
```

How can I do this with a String.replaceAll ?

I have tried `replaceAll("FLOAT(.*?)", "53")` and it just replaces the `FLOAT` so the string looks like:

```
"TestValue 1 VARCHAR(10), TestValue2 53(126), TestValue3 53(135)"
```

Comment: Why don't you do `replaceAll("T\(\\d+\)", "T(53)");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\(` and `\)` to escape the literal parenthesis, and then `\d+` to match digits. Something like,

```
String s = "TestValue1 VARCHAR(10), TestValue2 FLOAT(126), TestValue3 FLOAT(135)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("FLOAT\\(\\d+\\)", "FLOAT(53)"));
```

Output is (as requested)

```
TestValue1 VARCHAR(10), TestValue2 FLOAT(53), TestValue3 FLOAT(53)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler - your replacement is fixed (it doesn't depend on the matched text) - you always want to replace with `FLOAT(53)`

So use regex

```
FLOAT\(\d+\)
```

and replacement

```
FLOAT(53)
```